# Create Meteor User through PHP

Tags: php, joomla, meteor

I have a Meteor application running together with a PHP application. The users are all created through PHP (using Joomla). Right now we're syncing the users through the MYSQL database into mongo. But I was thinking of creating the users directly from PHP. A simple joomla plugin for mongoDB let's me insert into the users table like this:

```
$m = new mongoDatabase ( 'xyz' ); 
$db = $m->getDB();
if($db != "error")
{
    $collection = $db->users;  
    $user = array("username" => "foo", "emails" => array( "address" => "foo@bar.com", "verified" => "NO" ), "services" => array ( "password" =>  array( "srp" => "Meteor._srp.generateVerifier('bar')" )));
    $collection->insert($user);
}
```

Of-course, the password doesn't get a Identity, a salt and a verifier which Meteor generates when we run the Meteor._srp.generateVerifier function is executed within the meteor framework. Is there a way to manually create the salt, indentity and the verifier. The other option would be to expose a REST based API within Meteor.

Comment: Why not use the Joomla API for creating the salt before you send it over> Also the crypted password in joomla has the salt attached.

Comment: I had done some research on doing something similar.  Why not connect Meteor directly to the MySQL db? Here is info on the REST API: https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi and some info on connecting Meteor to MySQL: http://www.fastcolabs.com/3007015/how-use-mysql-meteor